# Find Nearst Neighbor Excel Algorithm

Tags: excel, algorithm, excel-formula, nearest-neighbor

I have two columns; x and y coordinates. I want to find each point's nearest neighbor (not knn) and its distance. I tried using a formula to create a massive grid of distances to which I could sort, but it incorrectly autofills when I drag it to other cells. It's way too many points to try to do manually.

I either need help with an Excel formula that will do it for me, or a suggestion of an application with an algorithm that will complete this task.

Any ideas?

This is what I have:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.2 |
| 3.2 | 1.8 |
| etc | etc |

And I want something like this:

| DISTANCES | Point 1 | Point 2 | Point 3 | Point 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Point 1 | 0 | 1.5 | 2.0 | 1.2 |
| Point 2 | 1.5 | 0 | 2.9 | 3.0 |
| Point 3 | 2.0 | 2.9 | 0 | .05 |
| Point 4 | 1.2 | 3.0 | .05 | 0 |

Comment: Please dd some data in your question and show what you need as a result from that data and share what you've tried do far.

Comment: Index() with match() may work, match() has an argument for exact, ascending or descending matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solution works for versions of Excel that support dynamic arrays*

Using the Euclidean distance formula, F2 is `=SQRT((B2:B5-TRANSPOSE(B2:B5))^2+(C2:C5-TRANSPOSE(C2:C5))^2)`.

[image: Sample solution]